# Validity of coordinate transformations in the asymptotic limit

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, supergravity

I have been working on some planar black hole solutions in $4D$ supergravity and by solving the equations of motion I have found the metric which is of the form:

\begin{equation}
 ds^2 = \dfrac{W(r)}{H(r)} dt^2 + \dfrac{H(r)}{ W(r) r^4} dr^2 + H(r)(dx^2 + dy^2 )
\end{equation}

Where $r$ is a transverse coordinate, $r \in [0,\infty)$ and the coordinates $x,y$ go along the brane $x,y \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

Where the functions $H(r)$ and $W(r)$ are a bit messy but both behave as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} H(r) &= \text{const.} + {\mathcal{O}} \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \right) \\
\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} W(r) &= \text{const.} + {\mathcal{O}} \left(\dfrac{1}{r} \right) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If I take the asymptotic limit, ($r \rightarrow \infty$) then the metric is of the form:

\begin{equation}
ds^2 = - dt^2 + \frac{1}{r^4} dr^2 + dx^2 + dy^2.
\end{equation}

My question is, is this the same as the Minkowski metric of the upper half plane?

If I make the coordinate transformation

\begin{equation}
r = z^{-1} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \dfrac{dr^2}{r^4} =  dz^2
\end{equation}

then we can recalculate the limits to find:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} H(z) &= \text{const.} + {\mathcal{O}} (\sqrt{z})  \\
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} W(z) &= \text{const.} + {\mathcal{O}} \left(z \right) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

plugging this back into the metric in the limit of $z \rightarrow 0$ gives us something that now looks like the standard Minkowski metric of the upper half plane:

\begin{equation}
ds^2 = - dt^2 + dz^2 + dx^2 + dy^2
\end{equation}

but $z$ is directed from $\infty$ towards $0$. Does the inverted coordinate differentiate this metric from Minkowski? If so, can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing telling you the "direction" in which you should travel a given coordinate. Therefore $z \in [0,\infty)$ is the same as $z \in (\infty,0]$.

If you have further doubts, compute the Riemann tensor, you will find that is zero, meaning that the space is indeed Minkowski.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't see the forest for the trees and didn't think of something as simple as looking at the Riemann tensor.